# Proc append and addressing excel sheets

Tags: sas

I'm using this code to update an Excel sheet:

```
libname xls excel '..\append.xls' ver=2002;

proc datasets lib = xls nolist;
delete output;
quit;

data xls.output;
set Ongoing_SE;
run;
libname xls clear;
```

The above part creates the output file.

```
libname xls excel '..\append.xls' scan_text = no ver=2002 ;

proc append  
base = xls.output
data = Ongoing_SE;
run;
libname xls clear;
```

I want to append data into specific sheets of the excel file but I don't know how to address excel sheets.

/Johan

Answer (score 0):

Excel sheets are normally addressed as

```
libname.'SheetName$'n
```

So in yuor case,

```
xls.'Output$'n
```

The `'something'n` construct is a 'named literal' which is equivalent to a non-quoted string - such as a variable name, a library name, etc.  It's how you construct an otherwise-illegal name in SAS, such as the sheet name that contains a silent '$'.

If you created the sheet in SAS (such as with `xls.Output`), you can refer to it either as `xls.output` or `xls.'output$'n`.  If it was created in Excel, you probably will have to use the second form.

Comment: Thanks! You made me realize how to make multiple sheets within the same file, which more or less solves my problem. And the refering works fine too :)